# How to integrate this "$\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{5}{4}x^3-\frac{93}{32}x^2+\frac{95}{24}x}{1+e^{\beta (x-x_0)}}$"

Tags: calculus

I do some project about  harmonic oscillator potential in QM and need to find this term, but I don't know how to integrate this one. When, $\beta >0$

Comment: Please also write the integral in the question text for us mobile app users

Comment: Where is the numerator coming from ? It looks like the beginning of a series expansion. It is the case ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found this one in the method for finding density of state of harmonic oscillator. It's look very cool if you met it in some series expansion. Nature is wonderful. LOL

Answer (score 4):

This is not an easy problem which requires special function since, for $\beta >0$ and $n \geq0$,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+e^{\beta  (x-a )}}\,dx=- \frac{\Gamma (n+1) }{ \beta ^{n+1}}\,\,\text{Li}_{n+1}\left(-e^{ \beta a}\right)$$

If $a=0$ this would give for the integral
$$\frac{190 \pi ^2 \beta ^2-2511 \beta  \zeta (3)+42 \pi ^4}{576 \beta ^4}$$

If the integral was for $a$ to $\infty$, letting $x=y+a$ would lead to integrals
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{y^n}{1+e^{\beta  y}}\,dy=\frac{ \left(2^n-1\right)  \zeta (n+1) \Gamma (n+1)}{2^n\,\beta^{n+1} }$$ and your numerator would be
$$\frac{1}{96} \left(120 a^3-279 a^2+380 a\right)+\frac{1}{48} \left(180 a^2-279
   a+190\right) y+\left(\frac{15 a}{4}-\frac{93}{32}\right) y^2+\frac{5
   }{4}y^3$$ and the result of the integral would be
$$\frac{a \left(120 a^2-279 a+380\right) \log (2)}{96 \beta }+\frac{\pi ^2 \left(180
   a^2-279 a+190\right)}{576 \beta ^2}+\frac{9 (40 a-31) \zeta (3)}{64 \beta
   ^3}+\frac{7 \pi ^4}{96 \beta ^4}$$

**Edit**

Concerning the term
$$\text{Li}_{n+1}\left(-e^{ \beta a}\right)$$ if $a$ is small, we could expand it as
$$-\left(1-2^{-n}\right) \zeta (n+1)-a \beta  2^{-n} \left(2^n-2\right) \zeta (n)-a^2
   \beta ^2 2^{-n-1} \left(2^n-4\right) \zeta (n-1)-\frac{1}{3} a^3 \left(\beta ^3
   2^{-n-1} \left(2^n-8\right) \zeta (n-2)\right)+O\left(a^4\right)$$